# unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms webdriver firefox

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium

I am trying to test with selenium webdriver, I got the below error

> unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms webdriver firefox

This is my code

```
IWebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

I'm stuck here, can't go for feature implementation. Any one help me from out of this.

My Firefox version was `42.0`

Comment: Did you try with the answers for the same question around here? http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=unable%20to%20bind%20to%20locking%20port%20%20within%20webdriver%20firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bind error usually occurs due to incompatibility between firefox and Selenium. Please check the version of your firefox and selenium. You might be using a older Selenium version.
You can download the latest selenium server from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but., i have same dll, that you're mention. but still the problem occurs.

Comment: Please share the exact firefox version and selenium version you are using.

Comment: Ya sure Firefox version 42.0 and selenium version 2.2

Comment: selenium version 2.2?? Latest selenium version is 2.48. Please goto the link in the answer and download the selenium dll files to latest

Comment: Yes now i have Latest selenium version 2.48 and visual studio .net frame work 4.0, But still the same happened